# A container with the right dimension, height setting, And footer need to be the figure with icon, font-awesome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on one of the bootstrap challenges, and I guess I am in the last part that I could complete the landing page; however, I got some minor issue regarding the container in div and the footer issue.

I am trying to set up the container with a limited dimension with height and weight.  I want to know should I add up any CSS to target the container?

Second, I need to create some social icon with round and radius, and I have input "btn btn-dark btn-floating with the code by fab fa-twitter.  However, it shows only a little peanut of the small square in the front.

Please kindly advise the way to input, or am I missing something that is not enough.

I believe this is necessary for me to add padding to let the footer fit all contents in the middle of the site.

Please do give me some advice about how could I fix all this issue.

The screenshot is what I need to complete

Thank you

[This is what I done till now](https://www.codeply.com/p/PB3TrE9NEG)

[image: This is what I need to complete]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help your second issue check out the link
[Social icon button round](https://www.codeply.com/p/PB3TrE9NEG#)